# Why are scripting languages used for server side tasks and not compiled languages?

Tags: asp.net, server-side

...Or are both used in tandem for each of their distinct features?

I have been trying to figure out why server side scripting is different that running a compiled program to handle web requests. I would really appreciate an example of the usefulness/use of server side scripting that makes it necessary.

I read this about ASP (I've been using ASP.Net without knowing much about it): "When a browser requests an ASP file, the server passes the request to the ASP engine which reads the ASP file and executes the server scripts in the file". I understand that this has something to do with customizing an html file with user data that was passed with the request for the ASP page (and the server-side scripts can/are kept secret by nature from the client). ->

Is this why server side scripting is used: it is easier to edit a dom with embedded dom editing scripting languages that were created for such purposes rather than use a compiled program that takes variables from a client to edit a dom on the server side?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well some systems do use script languages that run sever side.

And no, asp.net server side code does not run any of the JavaScript you have server side.

When you click on a asp.net button? the web page is sent to server. Then code behind runs, and then it is rendered and sent down to the client. So when you talk about code behind? You are talking about C# or vb.net code.

There is next to zero reason to try and run some scripting code server side. JavaScript is desinged and runs 100% in the browser, and thus is designed to run say without a compiler.

The advantage of client side Scripting? Well it runs 100% on the client computer, and thus no round trip or post back is required. So for a fast windows like experiance? Well, you start to adopt more and more client side code. The reason then is that the client software running in the browser can feel, respond very much like a windows desktop program.

So we see the rise of technologes like say ajax. This means that you still run browser side code, but that browser side code can now make "tiny" or "smaller" calls to the web server.  And in some cases asp.net can and will setup + inject some browser side code for you. For example, when you drop in a few text boxes, and then drop in a asp.net validator? Well note how fast and instant these validators work. (they work without a round trip! and without a post back!). So when you drop in these validoators into that web page? Asp.net will write and automatic generate the JavaScript to run in the client browser for you.

So, in asp.net, there would be little gain and benefit to use a scripting language to run server side when that code can (and should) run all great in the browser. And who would want to give up a great IDE and development language like c# or vb.net, and have to write in some difficult language like JavaScript?

But because we want more and more "responsive" applications that run in a browser? Then more and more effort is being spent on this simple question:
How can we have more and more code and logic run 100% in the browser, since then that means the user interaction will occur 100% local, and without having to hit the server. This not only reduces the server workload, but also means that the response time becomes more and more like a desktop program. The advent of ajax and other approaches means that you can now run a spreadsheet 100% in a browser.

And what do you think all the hub-bub is about blazer? In a nutshell, blazer is simply a technology that allows say your server side c# code to now be written to run 100% in the client browser. The advanage of this means not only do you get to write in one language, but now that c# code can run either server side, or browser side. Again, this concept is a attempt to allowing developers to push more and more code down to the browser to run in place of code having to run server side. Now server side code is not a bad thing, but if you require a post back or sending the web page up to the server for that code to run? Well, then it takes time, and thus you don't get a fantastic interactive web application like you do say with 100% desktop software.

In fact the interaction we now have available with a combination of web side and server side code? Well, we have the ability to create a really fantastic user experience, and now web applications can run, feel and respond just as good as what a typical desktop application can achieve, but requires no software install.

So at the end of the day? No, there is little reason to want to run some Scripting code server side. And in the case of asp.net? None of your JavaScript code does run server side - it quite much used for code that runs in the browser.

There are few reasons to want or have Scripting code run server side. This really all comes down to how the web works. But if you can push more and mode code to the client side? Then you will. And as the tools get better and better? Well, they allow more and more code with greater ease to be run in the browser side. (that's what blazer is all about).

So, if you write a cute tic tac toe game? Well, you could write it 100% to run browser side. And that means zero load and stress on the web site. And it also means that the user gets a desktop like user experience. (and in fact they ARE running that game 100% with browser side code).

So just keep in mind, that none of your JavaScript in asp.net runs server side - that js is used for code and interaction that runs in the browser side - and thus does not need some post back or even to talk with the server. However, you can call say a sub or function you do have in that web page (with a js ajax call).

So it not necessary easier to use/change/edit parts of the DOM server side or client side. But hey, if you CAN do that editing or changes 100% client side, then you should, as then  you not need to talk to the server. However, the client side code does not have nor allow you to do things like say write a sql query, and fill a table. It needs to talk to the server to do that. And thus you can use your really great server side coding system to pull that data. And the other issue is security. If I can write some browser code to pull data from a datbase? Well, then i will go hit amazon.com and steal all their data!

So, JavaScript is VERY limited. It can't do things like say go and grab a file on your disk drive and up-load it to the server. If  you could do that, then when you visit my side, I would run some code to grab your outlook or even some spreadsheet called passwords.xls and upload it. So for reasons of security, the code that runs in the browser BETTER be VERY limited in what resources and things it can do on your computer - else it too big of a security risk. But computer running on my web site and my server? Well, I want that code to do anything, including things like process your credit card or have use of say banking information.

Comment: Thank you for the very explicatory response. It helped me realize that server-side scripting is just a technique used by servers programs.

Comment: The main issue is that scripting languages don't allow disk/file operations. So you can't say write code to open a file and read it. it simply not allowed. And you can't say open a database and read some data (again not allowed). However, some people spend a lot of time writing script code, so they kind of like the idea to write the same code for server side. but as noted, it usually too limited. Now not all scripting systems are limited to a browser and some have zero to do with a browser or even run in one. But in the context of .net? Then scripting is in the context of browser side code.

Comment: Some scripting languages do have full features (file io/ database use etc.). But as such, these languages don't and can't run in the browser.

Comment: Your comments gave me a good perspective of when and where scripting languages are used and why especially in the context of ASP.Net core. Thanks.